# Keep the running processes alive when disconneting the remote connection

Tags: ssh, process

I have a bunch of processes on a server initiated by ssh from my own machine. It is now about three hours that my machine's Ubuntu has got hung and I do not see any other options but restart. Is there any way to keep the processes on the server alive? I have the root access to both my machine and server.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to achieve this:

#### `nohup`

use `nohup` to run the command so that the process is immune to hang ups (log out).

For example: `nohup command > /path/to/log 2>&1 &`

> **NOTE**: the above runs command immune to `SIGHUP` in the background and redirects `stdout`/`stderr` to a file specified.

#### `setsid` and `disown`

Use `setsid` and `disown` Basically this allows the process to run as a new session (`init` / PID 1 as its parent) so that user logout doesn't affect it. You can read the manual for more information.

#### **Recommended approach**

Use `tmux` or `screen`

Run command/apps in a `tmux` or `screen` session. I personally prefer `tmux`. Technically it runs a server on the host (remote server), as long as the daemon does NOT die, all session information will be preserved.

> **NOTE**: if you get disconnected, just ssh to the server again and run `tmux attach -t <target-session>` to get back to the sessions. Use `tmux ls` to list available sessions.