# Start background command over SSH

Tags: command-line, server, bash, ssh

**Problem:**

I want to pipe the output of `docker logs -f` ( for all containers ) into another command and keep it running on the remote server. I already found [Run a nohup command over SSH, then disconnect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349262/run-a-nohup-command-over-ssh-then-disconnect) but I had no success adopting the solution to this use case.

**What have I tried so far:**

```
ssh server << EOF
for cont in `docker ps -q`; do
        docker logs -f $cont 2>&1 | bunyan | /var/opt/go-logsink/go-logsink connect 2>&1 &
done
EOF
```

nohup version: `nohup "docker logs -f $cont 2>&1 | bunyan | /var/opt/go-logsink/go-logsink connect"`

Running that loop within a screen session works, but I want to automate the call after a deployment and that does not work. Also I tried calling `nohup "<command>"` within the loop and I see it creating the process, upon disconnection of ssh the processes get killed.

**Question:**

How to run that loop so it creates processes that stay alive after ssh session close.

Comment: How did you use `nohup` here?

Comment: And how did you use `screen`?

Comment: @Melebius I logged into the server interactivly. I mentioned my current workaround.

Comment: @muru updated question

Answer (score 1):

Screen or tmux may be what you're looking for, preserving sessions alive independently from SSH.